# How to set layout for a Blazor component programmatically?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-components

In Razor View there is a property named `Layout` that allows me to set the layout for that view with code, simply just like this

```
@{
    Layout = "_MyLayout";
}
```

Now in Blazor component is there something similar that allows me to set the layout for my component programmatically like in razor view?  All I see right now is that  the layout for a component can be hard coded with a directive at the top of the component like this

```
@layout MyLayout
```

It would be very helpful to be able to set it with code.

Comment: The direct translation of what a layout is in a Razor view would be a simple parent component that renders the contained ChildContent at a certain location. You wouldn’t do that with a Razor directive but just a custom component.